# My .float:right element is floating past it's containing DIV

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following simple nav bar in an HTML file with bootstrap loaded:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <ul style="float:left">

                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Womens-Fashion_W0QQfsubZ5511742012">women's</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Mens-Fashion_W0QQfsubZ5511743012">men's</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Youth-Fashion_W0QQfsubZ5511744012">youth</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Baby_W0QQfsubZ5511745012">baby</a></li>

                </ul>
                <ul style="float:right">
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo">STORE HOME</a></li>             
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

using the following CSS:

```
.listing-template .nav-bar {
    width:748px;
}

.listing-template .nav-bar ul {
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.listing-template .nav-bar a {
    color: #D7E3E9;
    font-family: oswald, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.listing-template .nav-bar li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D7E3E9;
}
```

My problem is that the element that is floated right is floating way past the containing DIV all the way to the edge of the page.  How can I keep the float:right element inside its div?  Do I need to clear the floats first?

Comment: If you are already using bootstrap you can replace your "float: left" with the "pull-left" class created in bootstrap.

Comment: I guess it's the width of `.container` breaking the layout . that class has fixed widths and acan be the issue try removing that and you will see

Comment: Thanks @Daniel-Pizon !  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the class `container`, that has fixed widths and it's breaking your actual layout:

From the Bootstrap CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

If you remove that then the `div` will have `100% width` and the float will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you would like to place a backgound on your navigation have a look at this solution.

```css
.container
{
    width: 748px;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCWVb54xv1i3ncYe1MCKY4vt9y7AdDMiCvthGjPTAXFJEzjjoy8w");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.leftContainer
{
    width: 200px;
}

.rightContainer
{
    width: 200px;
}

.listing-template .nav-bar 
{
    width:748px;
}

.listing-template .nav-bar ul 
{
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.listing-template .nav-bar a 
{
    color: #D7E3E9;
    font-family: oswald, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 8px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.listing-template .nav-bar li 
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #D7E3E9;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="nav-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="leftContainer pull-left">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Womens-Fashion_W0QQfsubZ5511742012">women's</a></li>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Mens-Fashion_W0QQfsubZ5511743012">men's</a></li>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Youth-Fashion_W0QQfsubZ5511744012">youth</a></li>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo_Baby_W0QQfsubZ5511745012">baby</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="rightContainer pull-left">
                    <ul>
                         <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stores.ebay.com/doboyo">STORE HOME</a></li>             
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This means that you will not have to change the overall size of you container, doing so could affect the overall width of you page if the container is the parent container for all elements.

Daniel has mentioned media-queries which can adjust your css based off the viewport size. These are really quite handy.

Comment: Thanks @KykeT !  I can see several possible applications for this method in my current project!